# Testing my model for hybrid scheduling in Embedded Systems

Tags: testing, modeling, embedded-systems

I am working on a project for school, where I have to analyze the performances of a few fixed-priority servers algorithms (polling server, deferrable server, priority exchange) using a simulator in the case of hybrid scheduling, where we have both hard periodic tasks and soft aperiodic tasks.

In my model I consider that:

- the hard tasks have a period equal to their deadline, with a known [worst case execution time (wcet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time). The actual execution time could be smaller than the wcet.
- the soft tasks have a known wcet and random interarrival times. The actual execution time could be smaller than the wcet.

In order to test those algorithms I need realistic case studies. For this reason I'm digging in the scientific literature but I am facing different problems:

- Sometimes I find a list of hard tasks with wcet, but it is not specified how the soft tasks parameters are found.
- Given the wcet of a task, how can I model its actual execution time? This means, what random distribution should I use considering the wcet?
- How can I model the random interarrival times of soft aperiodic tasks?

Comment: While there is a recommendation aspect to this question, I think there's also a stronger core ("how can I model X") that trumps it.

Comment: @AnnaLear I [edit]ed the question to wipe out shopping marks, feel free to edit it further if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the WCET - there is no definitive answer to this. WCETs tend to be highly pessimistic as, for a hard task, the task *absolutely* must be completed before deadline or your whole application is a failure (obviously firm tasks can allow some flexibility in this). I would suggest simply hard coding a distribution that ranges up to the WCET but where the bulk of tasks complete in something like 50% of WCET.

On the random inter-arrival times of soft tasks then a simple normal/binomial distribution of inter-arrival times should suffice. If you want to you can simply code this by giving the probability of the task arriving in a given period (eg 1 second) as  p  and set p to some value e.g., p=0.1 (in this case that means a mean inter-arrival time of 10 seconds). Then test against the value generated by your pseudo-random function (i.e., in this case if RND() or whatever gave less than 0.1 then your task arrives).